# Google Map - English Vs Japanese characters

Tags: google-maps

I recently came across a site http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html. This helps us to find the latitude/longitude of a place based on the address. If we enter an address of a place in English, it shows some latitude/longitude values. If we enter the same address in Japanese/Chinese letters, it shows some other values. What is the reason? Is it because Japanese/Chinese are 2 byte language?  Kindly let me know.